# Threading tasks for scanning open TCP port

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm having trouble with WaitAll in the below code. This method receives a list of IP Addresses and a port (I'm scanning for WMI port 135) and returns a list of IP addresses that have the  port open. I believe I do not have WaitAll implemented correctly as when I slow this code down, it seems to execute and return the correct systems. Thanks.

```
private static List<IPAddress> openSystems = new List<IPAddress>();

public static List<IPAddress> Scan(List<IPAddress> addresses, ushort port)
{
    int count = addresses.Count;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[count];

    //Loop through ip address
    for(int x = 0; x <= count -1; x++)
    {
        tasks[x] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Trying to get into {0}", addresses[x]);
                    tcp.Connect(addresses[x], port);
                    openSystems.Add(addresses[x]);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Can't get into {0}", addresses[x]);
                    //ignore exceptions
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    return openSystems;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? And how do you "slow the code down"? Also, you need a `lock` around `openSystems.Add(addresses[x])`, or use one of the [`concurrent collections`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Isn't ignoring exceptions _always_ a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are several best practices that are ignored in your code.

You should call the `ConnectAsync` method of the TcpClient and get rid of the call to `Task.Factory.StartNew`

You should not use `Task.WaitAll` but `await Task.WhenAll`

The method signature then becomes `public static Task> ScanAsync(List addresses, ushort port)` and you can await that where to code is called.

You are accessing the list openSystems for different threads. List is not threadsafe so you should use a concurrent collection or do it otherwise.

```
public static async Task<List<IPAddress>> ScanAsync(List<IPAddress> addresses, ushort port)
{
    var tasks = addresses.Select(a => CheckIpAsync(a, port);

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return openSystems;
}

private async Task CheckIpAsync(IPAddress address, ushort port)
{
    using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to get into {0}", address);
            await tcp.ConnectAsync(address, port);
            openSystems.Add(address);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can't get into {0}", address);
            //ignore exceptions
        }
    }
}
```

This might still not answer your question, since I can't find one. But it does show a better implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm unfamiliar with the best practices. I do not quite understand why ScanAsync is a Task type. I can't return openSystems to it. I have issues with the "await Task.WhenAll(tasks)" line in your code and also returning openSystems. Thanks for pointing out that I was not using a concurrent collection. Would you recommend a concurrent dictionary for this data?

Comment: @JoshuaEllis sorry I forgot an important part, I've updated my answer. I assume that the issues you were having is that the code in my answer did not compile.

Comment: Since we have an await statement in CheckIpAsync it has te return a Task.
Using the code of the answer you do not need a concurrent collection since we are not updating the list in another thread.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx for an explanation of async/await. Grasping the basics behind is is fundamental before using any Task related code.